# Pimcore: How to check if in editmode/admin area (in php)?

Tags: pimcore, pimcore-v5

Have googled this but cannot seem to find it... I have a (php) Listener class in which I need to know if i'm currently in admin edit page for a data object (similar to 'editmode' var in twig)... how to do this check in php?

Inside a Controller the editmode is available:

```
$this->editmode
```

but how to get this in a class that's not a controller (ie a listener class / any other class)?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to do same as the Controller (eg. FrontentController) does ?
https://github.com/pimcore/pimcore/blob/11.x/lib/Controller/FrontendController.php#L62

Thats the magic behind `$this->iseditmode`

Comment: As I said in my question, I'm not in the Controller when needing this...

Comment: may be this could help. new App\Controller\YourController()->container->get(EditmodeResolver::class)->isEditmode(); But the best way is to pass this value from the controller you are calling it.

Answer (score 0):

From https://github.com/pimcore/pimcore/discussions/13603:

PimcoreContextAwareTrait and PimcoreContextResolver